# How to bind a json object to model correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've been trying to send data to an API in order for the API to persist an operation in a database. I couldn't do it and I can't find the solution to it. Please help.

**Model Dto:**

```
public class NewRentalDto
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<int> MovieIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller definition:**

```
public IHttpActionResult NewRentals(NewRentalDto newRental){
   //todo
}
```

**Json objects sent through Postman:**

Attempt 1:

```
{
 "movieIds": [3,4]
 ,"customerId": 1004
}
```

Result: Exception

Attempt 2:

```
{
 "MovieIds": [3,4]
 ,"CustomerId": 1004
}
```

Result: Exception

Attempt 3:

```
{
 "Movieids": [3,4]
 ,"Customerid": 1004
}
```

Result: Exception

Attempt 5:

```
{    
 "customerId": 1004
,"movieIds": [3,4]
}
```

Result: Exception

I get the exception in the "todo" section of the controller when I try to access the newRental instance.
This is the message I get:

```
{
       "message": "An error has occurred.",
       "exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
       //more error info
}
```

Comment: Most probably the way you pass the data from the client is not correct I think that's why newRental is null. So you are getting null reference exception

Comment: How you are passing data from postman? can u attach a screenshot

Comment: You need to show what options you are setting (all options you have shown will work if you have set them correctly, and the method is a `POST`

Comment: The problem wasn't a model binding problem. It was that I wasn't initializing the data context variable inside the controller. @StephenMuecke

Comment: @JameelM Thank you for your comment. The problem wasn't a model binding problem. It was that I wasn't initializing the data context variable inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the verb that you are using when sending the object? e.g. the API is expecting a [HttpPost] or [HttpGet] ..

When I define an API endpoint I usually set the verb explicitly and where it is coming from.

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult NewRentals([FromBody]NewRentalDto newRental)
```

This will line up with the options you have chosen in Postman. If the verb is incorrect (e.g. the controller expects a "GET" and you are "POST"ing the data) then the instance of the object will be null.

Also. You may want to include Newtonsoft as a reference in your object and tag the properties as shown below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonObject]
public class NewRentalDto
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public List<int> MovieIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: At the moment I asked the question I've decorated the action in the controller with the [HttpPost] tag. But it's not shown in the code

Comment: Thank for all the other information about the JsonObject decoration

Comment: I solved the issue, It was that I wasn't initializing the data context, I was just declaring it. And I when I referenced it inside the action of the controller, I got a null instance. It wasn't a problem of model binding.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Are you Missing Headers "Content-Type" to pass your sample is working perfect

```
// POST: api/Default
public void Post([FromBody]NewRentalDto newRentalDto)
{

}
```

**Model**

```
public class NewRentalDto
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<int> MovieIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Posting Request**

[image]

**Debug View**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That part of the header was not missing at the moment I've asked the question

Comment: @IvanDerlich what was issue may i know.

Comment: The issue was that I wasn't initializing the data context I was just declaring it. And I when I referenced it inside the action of the controller, I got a null instance. It was not a problem of model binding.